# Can the same rune be used on multiple pages?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I wanted to start buying runes based on different build guides, can I use the same individual rune on multiple pages or can they only be used on one page at a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. The most copies of an individual rune you'll ever need is 9 (or 3 for Quintessences).

Comment: So buying the runes common to the builds I am looking at is a good way to get the most out of them.  Thanks.

Comment: I collect Runes not champions in LOL. You will get addicted when you start =)